# differences between the word "would like to, love and love to"

Tags: word-choice

> I would like to enjoy hiking.
>
> I love hiking.
>
> I love to enjoy hiking.

I am so keen to know if the words "would like to enjoy,love
and love to enjoy" are interchangeable.

Comment: And I would say "quite keen," not "so keen." "So" sounds a little bit sarcastic to me, but that might just be me and/or my American ears (eyes).

Comment: "I love to enjoy hiking" sounds redundant and non-fluent.  If you already *enjoy hiking* it sounds weird to say you *love to enjoy it*.

Answer (score 3):

They are not interchangeable.

> would like to
>   I **would like to** eat chocolate.
>   I **would like to** go for a walk in the rain.

expresses a desire for *something* which one doesn't already have

> love
>   I **love** chocolate.
>
> love to
>   I **love to** eat chocolate.
>   I **love to** take long walks in the rain.

express an affection for *something* which one already has

However, your last sentence

> I love to enjoy hiking.
>   I love to enjoy chocolate.

is not usually said since "love to enjoy *something*" would simply imply "love *something*" as the higher level of affection would win out.  However,

> I love to sit back and enjoy chocolate.

does work and is very enjoyable.